# Incorrect Master View Size in storyboard (portrait only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uistoryboard

I have an iPad app designed using storyboard, the MasterViewController simulated metrics are as follows:

[image]

and the view size as it appears in the size inspector is as follows:

[image]

when I `NSLogged` the view's frame in `viewWillAppear` method of the MasterViewController (named here HomeViewController), the result was: {{0, 0}, {320, **1004**}}

that means the actual height of the master view is 1004 pixels and not 832 pixels.

**why does Simulated Metrics in Xcode gives me incorrect master view height ?**

-Notes before you answer the question:

1. when I choose the orientation (in Simulated Metrics) to be Landscape, then the Master View's height would be 748 (in the size inspector) which matches the actual height when I run the app.
2. I know that FreeForm option in simulated metrics can resize the view to whatever I want, but each predefined size in the simulated metrics MUST give me the correct view size so I can design the view without ambiguity.
3. Xcode version is 4.6.2 and iOS simulator (iPAD) version is 6.1

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it came up when I was trying to search for the proper size of a 'master' view, so...  What the heck.

At a guess, this is related to the fact that both detail and master view have different sizes / shapes depending on orientation.  You'd think that apple would give the master view a width such that when you move into portrait orientation, the detail view's width is unchanged, but experience suggests otherwise.